# Why WeakSet can't be used with Symbol?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why it's not possible to `.add()` a `Symbol` in a `WeakSet`?

```
var ws = new WeakSet();
var sym = Symbol();
ws.add(sym); //error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only objects can be WeakSet members, but a symbol is a primitive. If you really need to store a symbol in a WeakSet you can wrap it in an object:

```
let ws = new WeakSet();
let symbol = Symbol();
let wrapped = Object(symbol);
ws.add(wrapped);
```